# Проблема с переходами к конкретным классам приложения

Tags: java, android

Во фрагменте пытаюсь обратиться к конкретным классам моего приложения.

```
   private void initializeAdapter() {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(persons, new Adapter.OnRVItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onRVItemClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = null;
                switch(position){
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                        break;
                    default:
                        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CustomIntro.class);
                        break;
                }
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Выдаёт следующую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы в метод передайте context для начала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но выделяет красным `context` подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно исправить эту ошибку?

Достаточно объявить и инициализировать эту переменную. Вам, кстати, это сама Android Studio говорит.

Comment: да спасибо, добавил, а как правильно проинициализировать?

Comment: @VadimMorozov, По-разному можно. В данном случае можно просто заменить `context` на `getActivity()`.

Comment: тогда intent в строке getActivity().startActivity(intent); пишет что might not have been initialized.

Comment: @VadimMorozov, Ну так Вы его инициализируйте чем-нибудь изначально. `null`-ем, например. Этот вариант тоже сама Android Studio должна была подсказать.

Comment: пробую и так, но становится только хуже. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Пробовал объявлять Context context = getActivity(); его прямо в этом методе, после чего он предлагает декларировать его final и сразу ломается весь метод

Comment: @VadimMorozov, Это уже совсем другая ошибка. Но в этом случае также Android Studio подсказывает, что Ваш адаптер не имеет конструктора с теми аргументами, которые Вы передаете. Поменяйте их местами.

Comment: да, спасибо, незначительные перемены там были) но помогли, а это главное!)